# Replacing repetitive document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

So my question is: is there a way how to replace repetitive `document.getElementById`? as I have a lot of them and as many may agree, the code does not look nice like this.

Below is a sample of what I have in my code.

```
document.getElementById('FieldAddClient').hidden = true;
document.getElementById('FieldAddClient').disabled = true;
document.getElementById('AddingClientTitle').hidden = true;
document.getElementById('AddingClientDesc').hidden = true; 
document.getElementById('DuplicatingClientTitle').hidden = false; 
document.getElementById('DuplicatingClientDesc').hidden = false;
```

Comment: Make 'em variables? Make a helper function? Use... jQuery...

Comment: I have tried putting them in variables but as I try to use them, they do not work. either I am doing it wrong

Comment: Are these elements within a form?

Comment: Have you considered hiding a parent container rather than individual elements?

Comment: This really depends on what you're actually doing. Except for `FieldAddClient` you don't really have repetitive calls (parameters differ and usage changes). As such to *reduce* perceived repetition, you could *alias* `document.getElementById`. But if you actually have repeating *tasks*, then identify that task and create a function for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't how many such statements you've and what exactly you want to do, may be you can give this a try.

```
function modifyDOM (id, type, hidden, disabled){ 
   if('hidden' == type)
      document.getElementById(id).hidden = hidden;
   if('disabled' == type)
      document.getElementById(id).disabled = disabled;
}
```

and access it like `modifyDOM('FieldAddClient', 'hidden', true, true)`

you can also have a list of all `id`s and call this method in a loop over that list.

Comment: I would add a parameter to know if the DOM element has to be displayed or hidden. (some have `.hidden = false;` in his code)

Comment: @iArcadia I have added type visible for hidden = false

Comment: My contention with this function is that it isn't "future proof", when (read: if) the time comes that you have to do multiple changes to multiple elements but to a different style property, you'll be back at square one.

Answer (score 4):

Make 'em variables:

```
var my_el = document.getElementById('selector');

my_el.style.hidden = true;
```

Make a helper function:

```
function el_by_id(s)
{
    return document.getElementById(s);
}

el_by_id('selector').style.hidden = true;
```

Make a deeper helper function:

```
function style(s, p, v)
{
    document.getElementById(s)[p] = v;
}

style('selector', 'hidden', true);
```

or, use [jQuery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/218388)...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use array of objects with the id and disable or hide as properties, like `{ id: 'test1', hide: true}`. see example below

```js
function hideOrDisable(items = []) {
  
  items.forEach(item => {
    
    if (item && item.hide) {
      
      document.getElementById(item.id).hidden = item.hide;
    } else {
      
      document.getElementById(item.id).disabled = item.disable;
    }
  });
}

function test() {

  hideOrDisable([
    {id: 'test1', hide: true}, 
    {id: 'but1', disable: true}
  ]);
  
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id='test1'>test 1</div>
  <div id='test2'>test 2</div>
  <div id='test3'>test 3</div>
  <div id='test4'>test 4</div>
  <button id='but1'>Hello</button>
  <button id='test' onclick="test()">Hide</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Function like this:

```
function _id(id){
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

and use it like this :

```
_id('FieldAddClient').hidden = true;
_id('FieldAddClient').disabled = true;
_id('AddingClientTitle').hidden = true;
_id('AddingClientDesc').hidden = true; 
_id('DuplicatingClientTitle').hidden = false; 
_id('DuplicatingClientDesc').hidden = false;
```

Comment: if this is your approach you might as well do `let _id = document.getElementById` without that clunky function definition.